# QtWebKit: call evaluateJavaScript with references to multiple QWebElements

Tags: javascript, qtwebkit

My objective is to evaluate a JavaScript function in a QWebFrame, passing it references to multiple QWebElements.

I am already able to evaluate JavaScript in the frame with reference to a single QWebElement:

```
QWebElement element1;
element1.evaluateJavaScript("return this.tagName;");
```

However, I would like to be able to evaluate a script that has reference to all of the elements. For example, if such a method existed, I would do:

```
QWebFrame frame;
QWebElement element1;
QWebElement element2;
QWebElement element3;
QList<QWebElement> elements;
elements << element1 << element2 << element3;

frame.evaluateJavaScriptWithElements("function(e1, e2, e3) {...}", elements);
```

A possible way is iterate through the QWebElements, and for each one, put it in a known location in the DOM. Then, call the script passing it all the elements as an argument. For example:

```
frame.evaluateJavaScript("document.myElements = [];");
element1.evaluateJavaScript("document.myElements.push(this);");
element2.evaluateJavaScript("document.myElements.push(this);");
element3.evaluateJavaScript("document.myElements.push(this);");
frame.evaluateJavaScript("(function(e1, e2, e3) {...}).apply(null, document.myElements);");
```

Although the method above works, it is dirty since it modifies the DOM (it adds the myElements array to the document).

Does anybody know a way of evaluating JavaScript in a QWebFrame with references to QWebElements' elemets in the DOM, without modifying the DOM like I showed above?